# Google BigQuery - why does window function order by cause memory error although used together with partition by

Tags: sql, memory, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I get a memory error in google BigQuery that I don't understand:

My base table (> 1 billion rows) consists of a user ID, a balance increment per day and the day.
From the balance_increment per day I want to return the total balance each time there is a new increment. For the next step I would also require the next day there is a new balance increment. So I do:

```
select 
    userID
    ,   date
    ,   sum(balance_increment) over (partition by userID order by date) as balance
    ,   lead(date, 1, current_date()) over (partition by userID order by date) as next_date
from my_base_table
```

Although I used `partition by` in the `over` clause I get a memory error with this query caused by the sort operation (the order by if I understood corectly?):

```
BadRequest: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 135% of limit.
Top memory consumer(s):
  sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98%
  other/unattributed: 2%
```

But when I check how often a unique user ID appears, the most is not even 4000 times. I know that I have a bunch of userIDs (apparently > 31 million as the image (see below) suggests, but I thought when doing a `partition by` the query will be separated into different slots if necessary?

Here I check how often a single userID occurs. This query btw. works just fine:

```
SELECT
  userID
  , count(*) as userID_count
FROM my_base_table
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY userID_count DESC
```

(sorry, in the image I called it entity instead of userID)

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Did I understand it correctly that the memory error comes from the `order by date`?
2. Why is that a big issue when I have less than 4000 occurences that have to be ordered when I use the `partition by`?
3. Why does my second query run through although at the end I have to order > 31 million rows?
4. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I run also in this issue. Also for queries which worked some month ago. I guess Google BigQuery restricted the addition memory usage. Coud you please try, whether it is possible to order this large table by user and date. If this is works, you can try to run the window function on the (pre)sorted table. This should reduce the key exchange over the nodes.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for your response. I was able to order the large table and got the ordered results but unfortunately, when I run my query on the presorted table I still get the memory error. Did presorting solve your issues?

Comment: yes, it worked. Could you try to only to run `Select lead(date) over (order by userID, date)  from (select * from your_table order by userID, date)` .

Comment: Hey Samuel, sorry, I was wrong, your solution with the presorted table worked for me. I had another count in my query `case when count(case when is_active then 1 end) over(partition by userID) > 0 then TRUE else FALSE end as is_active_user` that I did not mention. This part still throws a memory error, but everything else works fine - great. Thanks a lot! I try to fix the later as well..

Comment: Hi @smaica, Can you post your answer so that it will help the community members with their research as well?

Comment: This could be written shorter:  `max(is_active) over (partition by userID)`  or   `countif(is_active) over (partition by userID) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the memory issue by pre-ordering the base table by `userID` and `date` as suggested by @Samuel who pointed out, that preordering should reduce the key exchange over the nodes - it worked!

```
With ordered_base_table as (
Select * from my_base_table order by userID, date
)

select 
    userID
    ,   date
    ,   sum(balance_increment) over (partition by userID order by date) as balance
    ,   lead(date, 1, current_date()) over (partition by userID order by date) as next_date
from ordered_base_table
```

Thanks!